# jQuery autocomplete for multiple fields with same source - simple function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, field

I am working on a function `prepareAutocomplete(path, idArray)` in a js-file that is available throughout my whole application. So whenever I want a field to have autocomplete functionality it will look like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="employee_list" />
<input type="hidden" id="employee" />
```

In the text-field you will type stuff in and if you choose a result from the autocomplete list, it's value will be saved in the hidden field.

You would bind the autocomplete functionality to this field like so:

```
prepareAutocomplete("path/to/script/that/returns/results", 
                    ['listID' => 'employee_list', 'hiddenID' => 'employee']);
```

My `prepareAutocomplete`-function looks like this right now:

```
var autoCompleteItemsLoaded = [];   

function prepareAutocomplete(path, idArray){
    // first checking if data has been fetched from database before
    if(!(path in autoCompleteItemsLoaded)){ 
        // if not, get the data from the database
        $.ajax({
          url: path,
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false,
          success: function(data) {
           var items = [];

            data.forEach(function(item){
                items.push({label: item["name"], value: item["id"]}); // store data in items-array
            });

            autoCompleteItemsLoaded[path] = items; // store items-array in array that has all loaded items
          }
        });
    }

    var items = autoCompleteItemsLoaded[path];

    for(var key in idArray){
        $('#'+idArray[key].listID).autocomplete({
          source: items,
          messages: {
            noResults : '',
            results: function(){}
          },
          select: function(event, ui){
            this.value = ui.item.label;
            return false;
          },
          change: function(event, ui){
            if(this.value == '' || this.value == null){
                $("#"+idArray[key].hiddenID).val('');
            }else if(ui.item != null){
                $("#"+idArray[key].hiddenID).val(ui.item.value);
            }
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Now this code **works** if I have just **one field** in the idArray. But as soon as I work with multiple fields in the idArray, for example if I have **more than one** employee-field on the same page (of course with different IDs!), it **does not work** as it should. It shows the autocomplete-stuff in every field, which is correct, but if you select a result, the value of the LAST field in the idArray is changed!

I can't figure out why. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `prepareAutocomplete("path/to/script/that/returns/results", 
                    ['listID' => 'employee_list', 'hiddenID' => 'employee']);` I am not sure I understand what you mean by `['listID' => 'employee_list', 'hiddenID' => 'employee']`. I think you meant to write `[{'listID': 'employee_list', 'hiddenID': 'employee'}]` which means that per your design, if you want to work with multiple `autocomplete` binds, you would have to call the function as follows:

```
prepareAutocomplete("path/to/script/that/returns/results",
[{'listID': 'employee_list1', 'hiddenID': 'employee1'},
{'listID': 'employee_list2', 'hiddenID': 'employee2'},
{'listID': 'employee_list3', 'hiddenID': 'employee3'}]);
```

Then your `for` loop need a closure as follows:

```
for(var key in idArray){
    (function( arr ) {
        $('#' + arr.listID).autocomplete({
          source: items,
          messages: {
            noResults : '',
            results: function(){}
          },
          select: function(event, ui){
            this.value = ui.item.label;
            return false;
          },
          change: function(event, ui){
            if(this.value == '' || this.value == null){
                $("#" + arr.hiddenID).val('');
            }else if(ui.item != null){
                $("#" + arr.hiddenID).val(ui.item.value);
            }
          }
        });
    })( idArray[key] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! You are right about the function-call, it has to be `prepareAutocomplete("path/to/script/that/returns/results",
[{'listID': 'employee_list1', 'hiddenID': 'employee1'},
{'listID': 'employee_list2', 'hiddenID': 'employee2'},
{'listID': 'employee_list3', 'hiddenID': 'employee3'}]);`.
I've made the changes to the for-loop and it works now! The only problem left is that prepopulated employee-fields are reset. Do you have a fix for that?

Comment: Glad to hear it's working! *Employee-fields are reset*? Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I mean that on page-load the text-fields, for example those for employees, are filled with data, that has been saved there earlier. So you wanna update those fields basically. But shortly after the fields have been filled with the saved data, their and the hidden-fields' values are emptied

Comment: Never mind, I found the solution and it doesn't have anything to do with this question here :) thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, I understand now. On page load you can check to see if the employee fields have a value, and if they do, trigger `autocomplete's select` method so that the hidden fields can be populated.